# how to enable persistance storage in firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on react-native with firestore and creating an offline application. The data should be stored in firestore when there is an healthy internet connection. If not, it should be stored in cache.

In firestore, there is an Enable offline data where the data can be stored offline. But, I didn't understand what and where exactly I've to write into that.

So anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

in your firebase  file immediately after

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebbaseConfig)

firebase.firestore()
    .enable persistence()
    .catch(err => console.log(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) states:

> To use offline persistence, you don't need to make any changes to the
>   code that you use to access Cloud Firestore data. With offline
>   persistence enabled, the Cloud Firestore client library automatically
>   manages online and offline data access and synchronizes local data
>   when the device is back online.

So, you don't have to do anything to take this default behavior.

Comment: thnq @doug but in the same documentation it was written that by default offline persisence is enabled in Android and iOS and not for web. For web, it is disbled by default.

Comment: OK, it sounds like you know everything you need to know after reading that page of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore maintains copy of data locally, so even it writes data in offline and fetch it.

If you want to enable firestore persistence in your react native app, just copy paste the code from documentation to App.js, I am using the same and it is working fine.

Comment: I've added the enablePersistance() code from the firestore docs as you have suggested but I'm getting a warning that  Error enabling offline storage. Falling back to storage disabled: This platform is either missing indexedDB or is known to have an incomplete implementation. Offline persistence has been disabled

Comment: It might be regarding the native SDK,